# Slackware NFS issues

Tags: nfs, slackware

I'm having trouble accessing my NFS share. It's actually a Slackware boot disk "NFS" issue. When trying to access the share, I get the following message:

```
mount: RPC: Port mapper failure -  RPC: Timed out
```

Here's some pertinent information:

```
catch22bbs:~ # rpcinfo -p

program vers proto   port  service                                               
100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper                                            
100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper                                            
100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper                                            
100000    4   udp    111  portmapper                                            
100000    3   udp    111  portmapper                                            
100000    2   udp    111  portmapper                                            
100005    1   udp  20048  mountd                                                
100005    1   tcp  20048  mountd                                                
100005    2   udp  20048  mountd                                                
100005    2   tcp  20048  mountd                                                
100005    3   udp  20048  mountd                                                
100005    3   tcp  20048  mountd                                                
100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs                                                   
100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
100227    2   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
100227    2   udp   2049  nfs_acl
100227    3   udp   2049  nfs_acl
100021    1   udp  53359  nlockmgr
100021    3   udp  53359  nlockmgr
100021    4   udp  53359  nlockmgr
100021    1   tcp  44247  nlockmgr
100021    3   tcp  44247  nlockmgr
100021    4   tcp  44247  nlockmgr
100011    1   udp    692  rquotad
100011    2   udp    692  rquotad
100011    1   tcp    693  rquotad
100011    2   tcp    693  rquotad
100024    1   udp  56306  status
100024    1   tcp  59686  status

catch22bbs:~ # showmount -e 192.168.1.26

Export list for 192.168.1.26:
/var/nfs 192.168.1.26/255.255.255.0

catch22bbs:~ # cat /etc/exports

/var/nfs        192.168.1.26/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

catch22bbs:~ # cat /etc/hosts.allow

portmap: 192.168.1.33
lockd: 192.168.1.33
rquotd: 192.168.1.33
mountd: 192.168.1.33
statd: 192.168.1.33
rpcbind: 127.0.0.1

catch22bbs:~ # cat /etc/hosts.deny

http-rman : ALL EXCEPT LOCAL
portmap:ALL
lockd:ALL
mountd:ALL
rquotad:ALL
statd:ALL

catch22bbs:~ # cat /etc/fstab

/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST31000524AS_6VPH1GC5-part2 swap    swap    defaults 0 0 
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST31000524AS_6VPH1GC5-part1 /       ext4    defaults 1 1 
192.168.1.26:/var/nfs   /mnt/nfs        nfs     rw,sync,hard,intr 0 0
```

I apologize if i'm stepping on anyone's toes, but i've exhausted almost every other avenue.

TIA,
JL

Answer (score 1):

It should go as a comment... Can you also please provide your iptables settings `iptables -L`?
Your configuration looks ok. In my case firewall rules were a root of this problem.